# Ruby Mechanize how to send multiple params with same name

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I'm trying to do a post request with uses multiple values for same name, html is similar to:

```
<input name="opt[]" value="1"/>
<input name="opt[]" value="2"/>
<input name="opt[]" value="3"/>
```

With mechanize I'm doing something like:

```
params = {'opt[]' => [1,2,3]}
agent.post 'url', params
```

With no luck.

I've tried with other options like `opt: [1,2,3]` with no luck either.

Comment: have you tried `params = [["opt[]",1],["opt[]",2],["opt[]",3]]` Seems like the [Docs](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize.html#method-i-post) and [This GitHub issue](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize/issues/132) both suggest that's the way to go.

Comment: Yes, that worked.  would you mind writing it as an aswer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Documentation](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize.html#method-i-post) for Mechanize and the discussion in this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize/issues/132) the proper way to submit these parameters is by using a 2D Array as follows

```
params = [["opt[]",1],["opt[]",2],["opt[]",3]]
agent.post 'url', params
```

While reading the GitHub concern it appears that this is a known functional constraint and that they are or are planning on making efforts to resolve this but for the time being this is the proper method of submission. If you would prefer to use a `Hash` structure manipulation would not be that difficult e.g.

```
def process_to_mechanize_params(h)
  h.map do |k,v|
    if v.is_a?(Array) 
      v.map {|e| ["#{k}[]",e]}
    else
      [[k.to_s,v]]
    end
  end.flatten(1)
end
```

Then you can use

```
params = {'opt' => [1,2,3],'value' => 22, another_value: 'here'}
process_to_mechanize_params(params)
#=>=> [["opt[]", 1], ["opt[]", 2], ["opt[]", 3], ["value", 22], ["another_value", "here"]]
```

Hope this helps. As @pguardiario pointed out a String would also be acceptable but I feel it might diminish readability.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to post them as a string:

```
agent.post url, 'opt[]=1&opt[]=2&opt[]=3'
```